# Can't redirect with status

Tags: slim

Controller is called with

```
$this->get( '/read/{slug}', \Rib\Src\Apps\Blog\BlogControllers\IndexController::class . ':index' );
```

Inside it I tried:

```
return $response->withStatus( 404 )->withRedirect( '/message' );
```

or

```
return $response->withRedirect( '/message', 404 );
```

but the response returned always has code 200.
How to enforce 404 ?

Comment: hmm it definitely won't work in my case. I remember trying a redirect with container and it worked.  Can't find the code, do you know how to redirect with the container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect with `404` status code. Only `3xx` is valid for redirection. When browser receives a `Location:` header it makes a new request to the given url. This means you could however redirect to a route which returns `404`.

```
$app->get("/test", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    return $response->withRedirect("/message");
});

$app->get("/message", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    return $response->write("Oh noes!")->withStatus(404);
});
```

Above code will redirect you to response with `404` status code.

```
$ curl --include --location http://0.0.0.0:8080/test

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Date: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:53:05 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: /message

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Date: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:53:05 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Oh noes!
```